# Await dosent wait?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I am currently trying to fetch something from an API. However, the fetch is quite big, and the fetch doesn't wait, so it returns undefined even though I am using await?
I know that the fetch works correctly and returns an object with over 2400 objects. However, it takes a while, and the problem is that it doesn't wait. It just returns undefined. So after 1 second, it consoles logs the result but then React is already done receiving the undefined.

```
app.get("/api/v1/getfrostdata",async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        let response = await FetchTemp();
        console.log(response)
        res.status(200).json({
            status:"success",
            data:{
                timeSeries:response
            }
        })
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

```
async function FetchTemp(){
    fetch('https://frost.met.no/observations/availableTimeSeries/v0.jsonld?elements=air_temperature',{method:"get",
    body: JSON.stringify(),
    headers:{ Authorization: 'MY SECRET'}
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(async(data)=>{
console.log(data)
        return data;
    })
}
```

Comment: "await fetch" in FetchTemp

Comment: Or you can just return the promise from fetch directly and get rid of the asynchronous annotation

Answer (score 1):

Await/async or Promise serve the same purpose, you're mixing concepts.

You either create a promise which fetch indeed does and use the exposed methods Then/Catch:

```
fetch(...)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(success => your success code here)
.catch(error => error code here)
```

Or you can use async await like this:

```
async function fetchTemp() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const json = await response.json();
  ...
}
```